# HTML elements in lxml get incorrectly encoded like &#x41D;&#x430;&#x439;

Tags: python, encoding, lxml

I need to print RSS link from a web page, but this link is decoded incorrectly. Here is my code:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import html, etree
import chardet

data = urllib2.urlopen('http://facts-and-joy.ru/')
S=data.read()
encoding = chardet.detect(S)['encoding']
#S=S.decode(encoding)
#encoding='utf-8'

print encoding
parser = html.HTMLParser(encoding=encoding)
content = html.document_fromstring(S,parser)
loLinks = content.xpath('//link[@type="application/rss+xml"]')

for oLink in loLinks:
    print oLink.xpath('@title')[0]
    print etree.tostring(oLink,encoding='utf-8')
```

Here is my output:

```
utf-8
Позитивное мышление RSS Feed
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="&#x41F;&#x43E;&#x437;&#x438;&#x442;&#x438;&#x432;&#x43D;&#x43E;&#x435; &#x43C;&#x44B;&#x448;&#x43B;&#x435;&#x43D;&#x438;&#x435; RSS Feed" href="http://facts-and-joy.ru/feed/" />&#13;
```

Title contents got correctly displayed by itself, but inside tostring() it got replaced by strange &#... symbols. How can I print whole link element correctly?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: not sure why you think it was incorrect. those are the UTF-8 encodings for the russian in the text, as far as I know. what were you expecting it to give you?

Comment: I think the OP expects actual Russian characters and not character references: П instead of `&#x41F;` etc.

Comment: Yes, I want to see actual Russian characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your program that works:

```
from lxml import html

url = 'http://facts-and-joy.ru/'
content = html.parse(url)
rsslinks = content.xpath('//link[@type="application/rss+xml"]')

for link in rsslinks:
    print link.get('title')
    print html.tostring(link, encoding="utf-8")
```

Output:

```
Позитивное мышление RSS Feed
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Позитивное мышление RSS Feed" href="http://facts-and-joy.ru/feed/">&#13;
```

---

The crucial line is

```
print html.tostring(link, encoding="utf-8")
```

That is the only thing you must change in your original program.

Using `html.tostring()` instead of `etree.tostring()` produces actual characters instead of numeric character references. You could also use `etree.tostring(link, method="html", encoding="utf-8")`.

It is not clear why this difference exists between the "html" and "xml" output methods. This post to the lxml mailing list didn't get any replies: https://mailman-mail5.webfaction.com/pipermail/lxml/2011-September/006131.html.